# computing first principal component of sklearn's PCA

Tags: pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, pca

I have the following code which successfully calculates the biggest principal component of my data:

```
lst = ['date', 'MA(1,9)', 'MA(1,12)', 'MA(2,9)', 'MA(2,12)', 'MA(3,9)', 'MA(3,12)', 'MOM(9)', 'MOM(12)', 'VOL(1,9)', 'VOL(1,12)', 'VOL(2,9)', 'VOL(2,12)', 'VOL(3,9)', 'VOL(3,12)']
df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name='daily', header=0, names=lst)
df = df.set_index('date')
df = df.loc[start_date:end_date]
pca = PCA()
pca = pca.fit(df)
print(pca.components_)
#print(pca.explained_variance_[0])
df = pd.DataFrame(pca.transform(df), columns=['PCA%i' % i for i in range(14)], index=df.index)
```

Is there any way to successfully get the first principal component without having to calculate it yourself? (does sklearn have some kind of attribute I can't find?)

My data:

```
            MA(1,9)  MA(1,12)  MA(2,9)  MA(2,12)  MA(3,9)  MA(3,12)  MOM(9)  \
date                                                                          
1990-06-08        1         1        1         1        1         1       1   
1990-06-11        1         1        1         1        1         1       1   
1990-06-12        1         1        1         1        1         1       1   
1990-06-13        1         1        1         1        1         1       1   
1990-06-14        1         1        1         1        1         1       1   

            MOM(12)  VOL(1,9)  VOL(1,12)  VOL(2,9)  VOL(2,12)  VOL(3,9)  \
date                                                                      
1990-06-08        1         1          0         1          1         1   
1990-06-11        1         1          1         1          1         1   
1990-06-12        1         0          0         1          1         1   
1990-06-13        1         0          0         1          1         1   
1990-06-14        1         0          0         1          1         1   

            VOL(3,12)  
date                   
1990-06-08          1  
1990-06-11          1  
1990-06-12          1  
1990-06-13          1  
1990-06-14          1
```

Output:

```
                 PCA0      PCA1      PCA2      PCA3      PCA4      PCA5  \
date                                                                     
1990-06-08 -0.707212  0.834228  0.511333  0.104279 -0.055340 -0.117740   
1990-06-11 -0.685396  1.224009 -0.059560 -0.038864 -0.011676 -0.031021   
1990-06-12 -0.737770  0.445458  1.083377  0.237313 -0.075061  0.012465   
1990-06-13 -0.737770  0.445458  1.083377  0.237313 -0.075061  0.012465   
1990-06-14 -0.737770  0.445458  1.083377  0.237313 -0.075061  0.012465   
1990-06-15 -0.715954  0.835239  0.512485  0.094170 -0.031397  0.099184   
1990-06-18 -0.715954  0.835239  0.512485  0.094170 -0.031397  0.099184   
1990-06-19 -0.702743 -0.024860  0.185254 -0.976475 -0.028151  0.090701     
...              ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...    
2015-05-01 -0.636410 -0.440222 -1.139295 -0.229937  0.088941 -0.055738   
2015-05-04 -0.636410 -0.440222 -1.139295 -0.229937  0.088941 -0.055738   

                PCA6      PCA7      PCA8      PCA9     PCA10     PCA11  \
date                                                                     
1990-06-08 -0.050111  0.000652  0.062524  0.066524 -0.683963  0.097497   
1990-06-11 -0.053740  0.013313  0.008949 -0.006157  0.002628 -0.010517   
1990-06-12 -0.039659 -0.029781  0.009185 -0.026395 -0.006305 -0.019026   
1990-07-19 -0.053740  0.013313  0.008949 -0.006157  0.002628 -0.010517   
1990-07-20 -0.078581  0.056345  0.386847  0.056035 -0.044696  0.013128   
...              ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...   
2015-05-01  0.066707  0.018254  0.009552  0.002706  0.008036  0.000745   
2015-05-04  0.066707  0.018254  0.009552  0.002706  0.008036  0.000745   

               PCA12     PCA13  
date                            
1990-06-08  0.013466 -0.020638  
...              ...       ...  
2015-05-04  0.001502  0.004461
```

Above is output from updated code, however it seems like it is bad output. The "first principal component" is defined as:

> this transformation is defined in such a way that the first principal component >has the largest possible variance (that is, accounts for as much of the >variability in the data as possible), and each succeeding component in turn has >the highest variance possible under the constraint that it is orthogonal to the >preceding components.

Is simply grabbing the first columns of the PCA fit the same process as the definition above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `PCA` object has a member `components_` which holds the components after calling `fit()`.

From the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html):

> **components_** : array, shape (n_components, n_features)
>
> Principal axes in feature space, representing the directions of maximum variance in the data. The components are sorted by `explained_variance_`.

Example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

np.random.seed(42)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate([np.random.rand(50, 5), np.random.rand(50, 5) + 1]))

pca = PCA(n_components=2).fit(df)

print(pca.components_)
```

Output: Two components in feature space

```
[[-0.43227251 -0.47497776 -0.41079902 -0.47411737 -0.44044691]
 [ 0.41214174 -0.54429826 -0.55429329  0.34990399  0.32280758]]
```

**Explanation:**

As stated in the documentation, these vectors are already sorted by their `explained_variance_`. This means by grabbing the first vector `pca.components_[0]` you receive the vector with the highest variance (given by `pca.explained_variance_[0]`).

---

It is possible to visualize this. As you can see in the code above, we want to find the two components (`PCA(n_components=2)`) with the highest variance. By further calling `pca.transform(df)` what we do is we project the data onto these components. This will result in a matrix `(n_samples, n_components)` in size - which also means we can plot this.

We can also transfor the vectors given by `pca.components_` in order to take a look on those two components in lower dimensional space. To make the plot more meaningful I first normalize the transformed components to a length of 1 and further scale it by their explained variance in order to highlight their importance.

```
t = pca.transform(df)
ax = plt.figure().gca()
ax.scatter(t[:,0], t[:,1], s=5)

transf_components = pca.transform(pca.components_)

for i, (var, c) in enumerate(zip(pca.explained_variance_, transf_components)):
    # The scaling of the transformed components for the purpose of visualization
    c = var * (c / np.linalg.norm(c))    
    ax.arrow(0, 0, c[0], c[1], head_width=0.06, head_length=0.08, fc='r', ec='r')
    ax.annotate('Comp. {0}'.format(i+1), xy=c+.08)

plt.show()
```

Gives:

[image]

---

**Special Update:**

After chatting with you in the comment section: Maybe take a look at [`FactorAnalysis`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.FactorAnalysis.html) ([see also](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/decomposition.html#factor-analysis)):

> Note that `df` is now a matrix with binary values (just like your original data)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.decomposition import FactorAnalysis

np.random.seed(42)

n_features = 20

# After 50 samples we "change the behavior"
df = pd.DataFrame(1*np.concatenate([np.random.rand(50, n_features) > .25, 
                                    np.random.rand(50, n_features) > .75]))

# I chose n_components here totally arbitrary (< n_features) ..

fa = FactorAnalysis(n_components=5).fit(df)
t = fa.transform(df)

ax = plt.figure().gca()
ax.plot(t[:,0])
ax.axvline(50, color='r', linestyle='--', alpha=.5)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Ah, so since they are already sorted, I can grab the first element of every sublist and that is my first principal component per row?

Comment: @ÉvaristeGalois Exactly. `pca.components_[0]` would be the first component and so forth.

Comment: `pca.components_[0]` is a list, so wouldn't `pca.components_[0][0]` be the first component?

Comment: @ÉvaristeGalois Well, no, the entire vector is the (principal) component. As the documentation says it is (n_components, n_features). I've adapted my answer a bit to visualize them.

Comment: So, I'm attempting to get the principal component for 6275  rows of 14 components each, I updated the OP with code that does what I believe you explained for me here, however the output seems very off. Am I missing something?

Comment: @ÉvaristeGalois I think you misunderstand what a principal component is. What you are doing in your questions code is transforming your data using your fitted `pca` instance. What this does it reduces the number of dimensions of your original dataset according to the principal components obtained by the PCA method. With `print(df.iloc[:,:1])` you just plot the first dimension all your transformed samples - these are not the principal components. Again, `pca.componens_` is an *array of principal components* sorted by their importance (variance).

Comment: @ÉvaristeGalois Each vector in `pca.components_` points into a direction *in feature space*. This means that the direction that the vector `pca.components_[0]` points at has a variance of `pca.explained_variance_[0]` and so on. At the beginning you tell `PCA` how many components you want to find - or in other words - to what dimension you want to reduce your data set to by setting `n_components` in the constructor. For each of the dimensions you want "*to find*" you'll get one "component vector".

Comment: @ÉvaristeGalois Regarding *feature space*: Your data `df` has `n_samples` (rows) and `n_features` (columns). All samples live in the same space. This space is `n_features` dimensions "large" - so this space is simply called "feature space". What PCA does is throwing away the dimensions with the *lowest* variance. Note that this is an *assumption*. PCA assumes that dimensions with low variance are not important. However, if this is true depends heavily on the data (and the task)!

Comment: by that logic, it isn't possible to have a scalar value for "PCA" for my set of technical indicators, which is what I'm trying to create. I adjusted the code & output again, and before when I could simply get the max of each row and call it the maximum principal component for any given day, I need to find the "first". If I use pca.components_, it is not possible or me to have the 6000+ observations I desire

Comment: @ÉvaristeGalois Well .. the problem is I am unaware of what you actually want to do. You obviously want to find a numerical representation for each day - since I don't know your task it's hard to help you here. And *please* do **not** think about just transposing your dataframe (`df.T`) - in that case the components would be 6000+ dimensional in size but you cannot simply pick the dimensions of a component vector and "assign" it to a day - the result would be meaningless.

Comment: My post now contains my initial data, which is a DF of technical indicators from 1990 to 2015. I'm attempting to use the first principal component of this set of technical indicators to construct a forecast later on. I assume this means a single scalar value for every date in my dataframe which is a PCA of all the technical indicators at that date

Comment: @ÉvaristeGalois Well, unfortunately this is still not enough to help you. It's not clear what exactly you're trying to predict and therefore it's not possible to tell what could be used in order to do so. Besides that, I think this would be off-topic for your question. If you need help solving your task maybe create another question (or you could post a proper description on https://datascience.stackexchange.com) where you can explain your data in more detail and in particular what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @ÉvaristeGalois I've updated my answer - take a look at the bottom - maybe FactorAnalysis can help you out?

Comment: as interesting as it is, ultimately I need to replicate some results and specifically by their definition they use the first principal component of a set of 14 values for every day from 1990 to 2015. It seems like factor analysis's results were very skewed

Comment: @ÉvaristeGalois Alright never mind. It was just a blind guess. ^^

Answer (score 0):

you can always use `PCA().fit_transform(df).iloc[:, 0]`, that will give you the value on the first PC axis for each row.

Comment: First principal component doesn't imply the first value on an axis, it has a specific definition

Comment: Well of course but since you already knew about `.components_` from your question, I figured you were looking for the values of your data points on the first PC axis since you were already printing out your principle components and transforming your data into PC space in your last two lines.

Comment: But yes, if you are just looking for the principal component itself, that is - as Stefan Falk correctly pointed out - `PCA.components_[0]`